# multipart/form parameter is coming null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, apache-commons

I'm trying to get the request parameters that are sent by a form enctype "multipart/form-data". I am using apache commons fileupload.

My code is below.

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List items = upload.parseRequest(req);
Iterator uploadIterator = items.iterator();

while(uploadIterator.hasNext()){
FileItem uploadedItem = (FileItem) uploadIterator.next();


if (uploadedItem.isFormField()){

  if (uploadedItem.getFieldName().equals("name")){
    name = uploadedItem.getString();
  }
}else{
  //Uploaded files comes here
}
```

The HTML code of the form is:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="ServletIncluirEvento"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
... //Here comes a lot of inputs (I changed the name of the attribute because I am from Brazil and the names are in portuguese)

<select size="9" id="idOpcoesSelecionadas" name="opcoesSelecionadas" multiple style="width: 100%;">
                                            <%  
 it =  colecaoUsuarioSelecionado.iterator();                             String name= "";
 while (it.hasNext()) {
 usuario = (Usuario) it.next();
 name += usuario.getName() + "/"; %>
 <option value="<%=usuario.getLogin()%>">
    <%=usuario.getName()%>
 </option>
<%
  }
%></select>

<input type="hidden" value="<%=name%>" name="name" />
```

Even so the parameter is coming null.

Someone knows how to solve?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which parameter ? Please provide more details !

Comment: I am trying to get the 'name' parameter that is passed by a input type="hidden" in the form. So when I run the code, the String name is coming null

Comment: add the form-related html code

Comment: I edited the post to put the code.

Comment: Are you doing the processing in the doPost ? is there a submit button in the form ?

Comment: Yes, I am doing the processing in the doPost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the problem, I redid the jsp page with a tag form enctype "multipart/form-data" for the images that I must upload and, for the other data, a normal form, wich I can get the request parameters normally.

I also did a refactoring to improve the logic.

Thanks for everyone for the tips.

Answer (score 4):

Modify  calling the method `equals`:

```
"name".equals(uploadedItem.getFieldName());
```

And generally speaking I would rewrite your code more clearly:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
FileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);
for (FileItem uploadedItem : items) {
    if (uploadedItem.isFormField()) {
        String fieldName = uploadedItem.getFieldName();

        if ("name".equals(fieldName)){
           name = uploadedItem.getString();
        }
    } else {
        // process file field
    }    
}
```

This allows to the code become a more comprehensible. It makes no sense to call twice method `getFieldName()`. And use [Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html). It add stability to your code by making check types at compile time. There's no need for casting in the time getting current object.

Comment: How will that fix the parameter being null?

Comment: I guess the loop doesn't reach the desired parameter with `name` **name**. Perhaps the form contains other input fields which doesn't have attribute `name`. In this case the NullPointerException may be thrown due to the fact that the traversing of the list was designed incorrectly.

Comment: It's part of how the library works; it iterates over the fields and you can check for the field name. It doesn't matter if there are other fields with a name of something other than "name", the loop would just skip over it (unless there's other code not shown, of course).

Comment: Hmm, I think you said that. In any case, I'm not sure the OP is getting an NPE, rather, the value of the field is null.

Comment: This loop would just skip over item only when the method `equals` doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: Correct. Which means there's another problem, or the OP needs to be asked to clarify what, precisely, is happening. It's quite unlikely the `.equals` would throw an exception--it's iterating over form fields, and form fields have names.

Comment: At the moment, I'm not with the code to test your solution, but tomorrow at work I'll check and tell you if it worked.

Comment: There are no exceptions when I run the code. The others inputs are text input, but this I take from the <select> and the File Uploader for a image. I can get all data but this parameter. And I use the same code to get the text inputs.